# Batch Script not running completely (but was working previously) - how to see errors?

Tags: python, windows, bash, batch-file

I've got a batch script that is pretty straight forward:

```
start "" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "cd C:\python-script && python run.py"
```

I've not done a lot with batch scripts before, but here I can tell it's just opening up git bash interactively, then running the command to CD in a directory and run `python run.py`

When I run this .bat from a cmd prompt, git bash opens up ever so briefly and then immediately closes but the script is never fired off.

Any way I can stop that script temporarily so I can see any error the git window may be throwing?

Comment: Try to change `cd C:\python-script` to `cd /D C:\python-script`...

Comment: add a `pause` at the end of the executed script, this will prompt you to press a key and will allow you to see the result of the previous command.

Comment: @aschipfl adding /D did not work. Also - adding a pause works to pause the CMD terminal but does not pause the Gitbash shell that is opened up - it opens and immediately closes.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - yes to the second part of your question. I'm sending the CD & Python command to be run inside the `sh` shell. I haven't tried with `&&` before the cd.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I misread, so skip the `&&` portion as mentioned.

Comment: what happens when you do `start "" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "python C:/python-script/run.py"` instead? also note the forward slashed in the path. or simply.. `start "" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "cd /D C:/python-script && python run.py"`

Comment: In either of those scenarios - the git bash window opens - something is there and it immediately closes before I can read any of it. I have this feeling it's because `python` isn't aliased on this Windows box yet for this user - but I cannot confirm.

Comment: Test it by getting rid of start. Do this EXACTLY in your batch file and run it `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "cd C:/python-script && python run.py" & pause`

Comment: Yeah, when I did that exactly as you had there - I got the message about python not being found. I'm not sure why it was working for the previous user - my guess is he setup a user specific environmental variable. I'll look into that and let you know! Thank you!

Comment: maybe always specify full path to python in your scripts.. `"%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" run.py`

Comment: So something like this: `start "" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "cd C:\python-script" "C:\python37\python.exe run.py"` ?

Comment: If you have Python 3.7 installed, then you may have the [launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) installed, so try `py.exe`, instead of `python.exe`.

Comment: @Hanny Yes.. like that.

Comment: Drags - no dice on using `py.exe` or doing it the way you suggested Gerhard. If I launch gitshell and cd into the directory and run the command it works as expected. `C:/Python37/python run.py`

Comment: Using `Start`'s `/D` option to set the working directory may also work for you, e.g. `Start /D C:\python-script "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "C:\Python37\python.exe run.py"`.

Comment: No luck with that either @Compo - I really think it has something to do with the python installation and calling it from the git bash window. Seems like odd behavior that it worked for one user, but doesn't run for me.

Comment: @Hanny Just run your batch file though the command prompt. This will allow you to see any errors that are thrown from inside your batch file and the prompt won't close immediately after unless you instruct it to do so.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - please post as an answer what you had written about explicitly calling the full path to python. It appears the issue is that the other user did have `python` set using an alias and once I was able to set it to use the full path to the .exe it started working (I think there was a script error at play, too, but that's beyond this question) - that did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to allow the pause to display in the current window, we can test by removing the `start` command to execute it in the local window. Also as mentioned in comments, if python is installed and it does not find it, it would require you to specify full path to it which should then work:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "cd C:\python-script" "C:\python37\python.exe" run.py
```